# Unable to use an axios plugin in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm attempting to add an Axios plugin to Nuxt as described [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend), but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my `plugins/axios.js` file...

```js
export default function({ $axios }) {
  console.log('Im in the axios plugin')
  $axios.defaults.baseURL = `https://localhost:5001/api`
  $axios.defaults.headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    console.log('Making request to ' + config.url)
  })
}
```

This is my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: ['~/plugins/axios'],
modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']
```

And this is where I use Axios in a file called `services/BookService.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  getBooks() {
    return axios.get('/Home')
  },
  getBooksFiltered(payload) {
    return axios.post('/Home/Filters', payload)
  }
}
```

I get the `console.log('Im in the axios plugin')` from within my plugin, but nothing else. `$axios.onRequest` doesn't appear to run, and the `baseURL` doesn't appear to be set correctly when `getBooksFiltered` is triggered. I get a `404` when it tried to hit the address `http://localhost:3000/Home/Filters`. As described in my plugin, the address should be `https://localhost:5001/api/Home/Filters`

I've also tried the following in my `nuxt.config.js`, but it doesn't work:

```js
axios: {
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:5001/api'
}
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

I've modified my `services/BookService.js` based on the suggestion below to the following...

```
export default {
  getBooks(axios) {
    console.log('Im in getBooks')
    return axios.get('/Home')
  }
}
```

My action request that makes my api call is the following....

```
import BookService from '~/services/BookService.js'

export const fetchBooks = (context) => {
  console.log('Im in fetchBooks action')
  return BookService.getBooks(this.$axios)
    .then((response) => {
      context.commit('SET_BOOKS', response.data.booksList)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

And my method in my component that calls the actions...

```
async fetch({ store, error }) {
  try {
    console.log('Im in index -> fetch')
    await store.dispatch('fetchBooks')
  } catch (e) {
    error({
      statusCode: 503,
      message: 'Unable to fetch books at this time'
    })
  }
}
```

I'm aware that I may be mixing async/await with promises incorrectly but I don't believe it's the cause of this issue.

Console returns the following...

[image]

My network tab contains a single request to `http://localhost:3000/` which seems incorrect. It should be `https://localhost:5001/api/Home` based on the plugin and the address specified in the action. It is also never entering `$axios.onRequest`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `axios-module` sets up an Axios instance on the Nuxt app instance. When you import Axios from `axios`, and use it directly, you're not using the previously setup Axios instance.

To fix the issue, you could either reference the preconfigured Axios instance from `window.$nuxt.$axios` (only in the browser), or setup your service to take an Axios instance as a parameter:

```js
// services/BookService.js
export default axios => ({
  getBooks() {
    return axios.get('/Home')
  },
  getBooksFiltered(payload) {
    return axios.post('/Home/Filters', payload)
  }
})

// store.js
import BookService from '~/services/BookService.js'

export default {
  actions: {
    async getBooks({ commit }) {
      const books = await new BookService(this.$axios).getBooks()
      commit('SET_BOOKS', books)
    }
  }
}
```

---

Another solution from [`nuxt-community/axios-module` #28](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/28#issuecomment-340743659):

> *~/plugins/axios-port.js*
>
> ```js
> import { setClient } from '~/services/apiClient'
>
> export default ({ app, store }) => {
>   setClient(app.$axios)
> }
> ```
>
> *~/services/apiClient.js*
>
> ```js
> let client
>
> export function setClient (newclient) {
>   client = newclient
> }
>
> // Request helpers
> const reqMethods = [
>   'request', 'delete', 'get', 'head', 'options', // url, config
>   'post', 'put', 'patch' // url, data, config
> ]
>
> let service = {}
>
> reqMethods.forEach((method) => {
>   service[method] = function () {
>     if (!client) throw new Error('apiClient not installed')
>     return client[method].apply(null, arguments)
>   }
> })
>
> export default service
> ```
>
> *Use:*
>
> ```js
> import apiClient from '~/services/apiClient'
>
> export default {
>   async current () {
>     return apiClient.get('...')
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: This isn't working for me unfortunately. Your proposed first solution isn't valid javascript - displays `; expected` and `Declaration or statement expected` in the `BookService.js`. I made a tweak based on your suggested principle - passing the axios instance into the service via the actions method but it still fails to run my request. I've updated my original post to show where I've put logging statements and what is returned in the console.

Comment: @Konzy262 Fixed typo in BookService.js (missing parentheses). Can you share a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I exported a customized axios instance as the doc suggested in my axios.js

```
export default function ({ $axios }, inject) {
    const api = $axios.create({
        baseURL:'/api'
    })
    // Inject to context as $api
    inject('api', api)
  }
```

Then use this.$api.get or this.$api.post in your getBook service
The above one works for me

Answer (score 0):

As I have just tested, in each request we should use $axios.
Example: `this.$axios.get('....')`, or in another context `this.$nuxt.$axios.get('...')`;
Because axios extension use with the app context instance, if we import, it will create a new instance which plugin cannot extend.

I have put test code on stackblitz: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-yqkvwx?file=pages%2Findex.vue,plugins%2Faxios.js,nuxt.config.js)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you need to `yarn add @nuxtjs/axios` or `npm install @nuxtjs/axios` like the setup instruction here before it can work: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup

I haven't experienced with nuxt yet but I don't think by adding some line of code into some js file without actually installing will make the package available into your repo.

Comment: I have the module installed. `modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']` is in my `nuxt.config.js`

Comment: @Konzy262 Have you tried `yarn add @nuxtjs/axios` or `npm install @nuxtjs/axios` to see if it works? Just copy your working repository to another folder and give it a try.